# How to implement a convolution neural network using RenderScript

Tags: android, python, neural-network, deep-learning, renderscript

I am trying to use a trained neural network to classify some images in my Android device.

So I found the class ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 and that's the only convolution I want to use. So I seams good, but I don't understand how to set coefficients of my network...

ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 asks for a 3x3 matrix, but the first weights matrix of net is of shape (3,3,1,8) in Python. This is totally different of what I should set in my coefficients.

What I am missing?